# Start ngrok via systemctl services on Ubuntu Server

Tags: boot, startup, systemd, services

I am running a Ubuntu Server 22.04.1 and trying to run ngrok at startup using systemd, to create a ssh tunnel.

Current state:

- BWS_ngrok.service under /etc/systemd/system/BWS_ngrok.service
- ngrok.yml under /home/ubuntu/server/bwsv4/ngrok.yml
- ngrok path: /snap/bin/ngrok (according to `which ngrok`)

/etc/systemd/system/BWS_ngrok.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Start Ngrok at boot
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target systemd-networkd-wait-online.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/snap/bin/ngrok start --config /home/ubuntu/server/bwsv4/ngrok.yml

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

/home/ubuntu/server/bwsv4/ngrok.yml:

```
authtoken: <Ngrok-Authtoken>
tunnels:
  ssh:
    proto: tcp
    addr: 22
```

What I have done in the console:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/etc/systemd/system$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
ubuntu@ubuntu:/etc/systemd/system$ sudo systemctl restart BWS_ngrok.service
ubuntu@ubuntu:/etc/systemd/system$ sudo systemctl status
```

Output of `sudo systemctl status BWS_ngrok.service`:

```
BWS_ngrok.service
× BWS_ngrok.service - Start Ngrok at boot
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/BWS_ngrok.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2022-09-13 19:27:11 UTC; 2s ago
    Process: 4734 ExecStart=/snap/bin/ngrok start --config /home/ubuntu/server/bwsv4/ngrok.yml (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 4734 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 239ms

Sep 13 19:27:11 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Start Ngrok at boot.
Sep 13 19:27:11 ubuntu systemd[1]: BWS_ngrok.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 13 19:27:11 ubuntu systemd[1]: BWS_ngrok.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

What I have tried so far:

- In the `.service` file: `ExecStart=/snap/bin/ngrok tcp 22` (Added the Ngrok-Authtoken before with `ngrok config add-authtoken <Ngrok-Authtoken>`)
- Checking the location of the config file of ngrok with `ngrok config check`, which gave me `Valid configuration file at /home/ubuntu/snap/ngrok/85/.config/ngrok/ngrok.yml`, so I added the following in this file:

```
authtoken: <Ngrok-Authtoken>
tunnels:
  ssh:
    proto: tcp
    addr: 22
```

But I still have not managed to get Ngrok to start at boot.